# Ngrx console logging any action with "on()" syntax

Tags: ngrx

Nowadays for ngrx store users recommended is to use in reducer "on()" syntax over switch statement.
It looks like below([docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function)):

```
export const scoreboardReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.homeScore, state => ({ ...state, home: state.home + 1 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.awayScore, state => ({ ...state, away: state.away + 1 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.resetScore, state => ({ home: 0, away: 0 })),
  on(ScoreboardPageActions.setScores, (state, { game }) => ({ home: game.home, away: game.away }))
);
```

I would like to console log all actions that comes to reducer. How can I do this conveniently in such syntax (I have so many actions)? Having old switch case statement I was achieving it simply by:

```
export function scoreboardReducer(state = initialState, action: ScoreboardAction){
   console.log('action', action)
   switch(action.type){
       // all handlers
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the redux dev tools? They will allow you to view all dispatched actions (though not only those passing through the reducer).

Comment: Yep, very helpful, but not working in every commercial project.

Comment: Do you to log actions for a specific reducer, or is all dispatched actions ok?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible anymore :(

You could do this though:

```
export function scoreboardReducer(state = initialState, action: ScoreboardAction){
   console.log('action', action)

   return reducerThatsUsingOn(state, action)
}
```